# how to create Pipe from a function in Angular?

Tags: angular, methods, pipe, transform

I have a batch of util methods, I want to turn them to Pipes in the fly.

```
function say(name) {
  return 'hi' + name
}
function go(name) {
  return name + 'home'
}


// do sth like this, I guess
// SayPipe.inherit(PipeTransform)
// SayPipe.pipeName = say.name
// SayPipe.transform = say;

// then I can use '{{ 'Tim' | say }}' in template
```

Comment: [Creating pipes for custom data transformations](https://angular.io/guide/pipes-custom-data-trans)

Comment: @YongShun create dynamic pipes, bro

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working example!

transform.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'transform',
})
export class TransformPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(original: any, func: Function): any {
    return func(original);
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<ul id="topic-listing">
  <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" />

  <ul id="topic-listing">
    <li *ngFor="let user of topics.users">
      <div class="single-topic">
        <span [ngStyle]="{ background: 'yellow' }">name - {{ user.name }}</span>
        <h3>{{ user.email | transform: go }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ user.email | transform: say }}</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

app.ts

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export function say(name) {
  return 'hi' + name;
}
export function go(name) {
  return name + 'home';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  say = say;
  go = go;
  term: string = '';
  topics = {
    token: 'eyefqffiwqnrfoqif',
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Admin',
        email: 'admin@yahoo.com',
        created_at: '2018-01-05 07:17:41',
        updated_at: '2018-01-05 09:17:41',
        outlet: {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Sarawak Energy Berhad',
          address: 'Kuching City',
          contact_number: '1300-88-3111',
          created_at: '2018-01-05 10:17:44',
          updated_at: '2018-01-05 10:17:44',
        },
        roles: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Admin',
            created_at: '2018-01-05 10:17:40',
            updated_at: '2018-01-05 10:17:40',
            pivot: {
              model_id: 1,
              role_id: 1,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example-i3gwk5)

Comment: turn to a pipe in fly, not implement a pipe in a explicit way, bro

Comment: The aim I want to achieve is that I dont want to import the methods to ts file.

Comment: @Rupert All the best!